# Multiple Xdebug users with VSCode accessing a single LAMP server over SSH

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, ssh, xdebug

What is the "correct" or suggested way to have multiple developers (2 in this case) using Xdebug from their Windows desktops to debug code running on a Linux server over SSH?

The standard configuration of VSCode for editing over SSH installs a vscode NodeJS server component on the Linux host, so when Xdebug is used it is that local server which opens port 9003 and VSCode communicates over the SSH link with that. Therefore a second client connecting will try to also open 9003 to localhost on the Linux server and fail.

Using a proxy is one solution to this, although I struggled yesterday to make it work using dbgbProxy (I also tried the Komodo Python script but that doesn't support current versions of Python). I did get php-xdebug-proxy working in the end. Even then it means that each client needs to set their own unique key within vscode and the browser they're using.

On the other hand xdebug's discover_client_host seems like a cleaner solution (at least for my use case where the server is a development box on the local network). But if there's a way to get vscode to use that I couldn't find it; I tried the alternative SSH-FS extension but I couldn't get the xdebug extension to work with the virtual file system despite that being supported by recent versions (the debugger ran but it was unable to map the file locations).

Either way I couldn't find any clear instructions online with example configurations, and a lot of what I did find was threads here and elsewhere that were years old and therefore out of date.

A working ssh-fs solution would be my preference, as I don't like having vscode-server installed on every server I touch - sometimes it's appropriate, others it isn't, others it simply won't work (eg on a system with a readonly filesystem). But I'd also be happy to get  dbgbproxy working as php-xdebug-proxy has a lot of dependencies to pull in.

Comment: Additional info: When connecting to dbgbProxy I get errors like this:

2023-10-26 15:08:29.247 [info] [server] Start new server connection from 127.0.0.1:57800
2023-10-26 15:08:29.248 [warn] [server] Handler response error: Error reading response: Error reading data: EOF
2023-10-26 15:08:29.248 [info] [server] Closing server connection from 127.0.0.1:57800

I have only found references to this alongside a DevSense vscode extension which I am not using,

Comment: Don't put additional info in comments, you can [edit] your question to improve it. That said, you can freely configure both the host and the port that the XDebug extension connect to, so it shouldn't be difficult to handle this scenario.

Comment: Rightly or wrongly (the latter!) I added the comment as it wasn't related to the main point of the question, which is "how should I do this" rather than "why is this specific attempt failing".

Answer (score 1):

If all machines are on the same LAN, then you can set `xdebug.discover_client_host=1`. It instructs Xdebug to connect to the IP address that was in the HTTP header, instead of the configured IP address (through `xdebug.client_host`). Remember that it is Xdebug that makes a TCP connection **to** your IDE.

VS Code (or any other IDE) needs to listen for incoming debugging connections — which is the same as for single-user connections.

Requesting a PHP script/application through the browser with Xdebug activated (either through `xdebug.start_with_request=always` or a [browser extension](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#browser-extensions)) would be enough for Xdebug on the server, to find the IP address of the machine that initiated the HTTP request. Xdebug will always want to connect to the configured port on that IP address (of the machine running the browser).

If the Linux server is **not** on the same network, then dbgpProxy can work, as long as PHP/Xdebug can connect to that debug proxy. You then need to configure and use these IDE keys so that the proxy knows where to forward the incoming debug request to. I have made a video explaining this in greater detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3RkGZK-UC8&feature=youtu.be

Neither the `discover_client_host` nor dbgpProxy methods do anything with SSH.

If neither the above-mentioned methods work in your set-up, then can alternatively have a look at [Xdebug Cloud](https://xdebug.cloud), which allows for debugging in more complicated scenarios.

Comment: For LAN use, discover_client_host is the way I'd like to operate. But I didn't find any examples of configuring VSCode to work that way, and my own efforts failed.

Whilst discover_client_host itself has no association with SSH, the issue is that VS Code has to have some way to interact with the files, and that is SSH. SSH-FS is the obvious way to do that but I couldn't find a way to make it play alongside Xdebug - the IDE would operate as a debugger and allow me to step through the code, but it couldn't show me the code in the editor (it couldn't map the files correctly)

Comment: @MarkRogers Do you have path mappings configured? They map remote file paths to local file paths — presumingly you do have the same files locally as remote?

Comment: I tried to map but failed, but couldn't find any documentation which said how it should be done for virtual file systems so I was just guessing. Support for virtual file systems is new, so anything older than a couple of years will tell you it can't be done, and although later docs do say it has been added as a feature I haven't seen example configs.

Comment: Does https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvElBs37JLg help? I need to write that into the docs still.

Comment: Thanks @Derick, yes that does help. Is there any way to parameterise the "ssh://remote-xdebug-org" bit to automatically pick up the host from the SSH-FS connection in use? Or is it necessary to create a separate debug configuration for each site even if they are otherwise identical in directory structure?

Comment: The `remote-xdebug-org` bit is just the name I gave to the SSH connection. It is not going to change per project, as long as you name your SSH remote host the same. I could just as well called it `remote-dev-server`.

Comment: I have several SSH connections to servers with identical structures. So my intention was to save the xDebug configuration globally, not in the project, which would only work if the ssh host could be picked up from the correction. (The VSCode way of using its vscode-server module works this way, in that if you're connecting to lots of servers then the xDebug configuration is consistent and only needs storing once)

Comment: Let me poke the developer of the plugin, and see whether he has an idea here. I do not :-)

Comment: Hi vscode-php-debug developer here. There is a lot to unroll here. I can't stuff everything in a comment, so let me first deal with your last question.
The debug adapter (the PHP debugger implementation in VS Code) has no idea about SSHFS. It only receives a server local path of a file. The path mapping is what is mapping `/var/www/xxx` to `ssh://server/var/www/xxx`. Ergo it also does not distinguish one remote server from another. 
Also the debugger configuration can only ever be inside the project folder.
Honestly I don't use sshfs so I'm not 100% how it behaves.

Comment: Please post what vscode extension are you using for sshfs and I can try to look at it in the evening.

Comment: This is quit a challenge. I had some local issues with VirtualBox Host Only adapter not allowing connections back to host and now I found out that SSHFS does not populate `${workspaceFolder}` https://github.com/SchoofsKelvin/vscode-sshfs/issues/178 . I'll continue to dig into this. You can have a launch.json on the remote host and/or in your local disk - inside the workspace folder.

Comment: It's actually "worse". It get's resolved, but to the remote path.
Instead of `ssh://docker/root/zobo/laravel/example-app` it gets resolved to `\root\zobo\laravel\example-app`. I'm going to make an issue out of this.

Comment: Fyi, filed an issue with MS https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/197377 and https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/pull/930 . I will write a more extensive answer a bit later covering the whole solution that you want. In short:

1. remote `launch.json` that works for all developers
2. dbgpProxy on server, or some other host where all developers can access it
3. IDE key in user local settings.json

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I was on vacation and for some reason I haven't convinced SO to notify me of updates to the post so I missed them until now. I have the same SSH-FS plugin installed as you looked at. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: To summarise what I ideally want (which I would have thought is quite a common wish but maybe not): (a) that two users can connect to the same host via SSH and debug PHP code there. (b) Ideally avoid the vscode-server requirement (lots of personal reasons - sometimes R/O filesystems, sometimes limited disk space, sometimes just not my server so I shouldn't be installing stuff there), hence the sshfs preference. (c) Ideally have consistent mapping scheme (eg ${workspaceFolder} that allows one config to work for multiple servers with similar structures (even if copy+pasted between them)

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you'd prefer using sshfs I suggest the following.

1. You will be running VS Code on your workstation, have a workspace folder - so you can store the sshfs config somewhere - and the server folder mounded via sshfs.
2. The `.vscode/launch.json` is going to be on the server side, because the path mappings should be the same for all users.
3. The debugger will be running on your workstation inside VS Code, and that means Xdebug (within the PHP server) will connect back to your workstation. This will be achieved via `xdebug.discover_client_host=1` php.ini setting.
4. Your `launch.json` will contain path mappings in this manner:

```json
{ "version": "0.2.0", "configurations": [ 
    { 
        "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
        "type": "php", 
        "request": "launch", 
        "pathMappings": { "/var/www/html": "ssh://server.domain.lan/var/www/html" },
    }
] }
```

The local path (`ssh://server...`) is hardcoded because there is currently a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/197377) in VS Code preventing normal variable subsitution.

After it is fixed the line could look like this:

```
"pathMappings": { "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}" },
```

Do not forger, you will also need a Xdebug Browser helper.

I suggest you use `xdebug_info()` to get an idea what is happening when you open the script in your browser.

There are also other combinations possible, so let me know if this does not work for you.